# How do you change the PROJECT_LOC in Zend Studio

Tags: zend-studio

Issue : I setup Zend Studio before I installed Zend server and start a important project. Now the `PROJECT_LOC` for this one project is in `C:\Users\Username\Zend\workspaces\proejctname\projectname`.

So it's not the end of the world, BUT it is slowing down progress when I have to move the files to the htdocs to test.

I searched online with no luck no how to change it.

If I right click on the project and go to proprieties, then click Resources/linked Resources, I can see it. But if I highlight it the edit button is not clickable. I search for a config file, but was unable to locate the value for `PROJECT_LOC`.

I have searched all the config files and the internet to no avail. Can I setup another project and import these files thus doing what I need without finding out how to change `PROJECT_LOC`.

Thanks for any help guys!

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem with Zend, several times in fact. I could never figure out how to fix it so I wood have to completely delete the project and re-add it. This would sometimes fix the issue and sometimes not so I just assumed it was an error in the install or on my computer.